# Transmitting a value from one function to another

Tags: javascript, function, call

This issue is asked already some times. But in the application of google apps script i can't solve this problem.

```
function two ()
{
  var bridgeclubs =   SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dfyI1jbz..........TVg4OoixKTz1");
  var bridgeclubs_sheet = bridgeclubs.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data_bridgeclubs = bridgeclubs_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var numRows = bridgeclubs_sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var sprshtname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
  for (var i=1; i<=numRows; i++)
  {
   if (sprshtname == data_bridgeclubs[i][6])
   {
      var A = i;         
      break;
   }
  }
}
```

In function one I do a call to function two, where I need this value A:

```
function one ()
{
two ();
//here I need this value A;
var C= 35 * A;for instance
}
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Could you not return it?

If you're not doing async functions, you can set `one.A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return value from function using `return i;` and obtain it in within  `one` by `var A = two();`.

```
function two() {
    var bridgeclubs =   SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dfyI1jbz..........TVg4OoixKTz1");
    var bridgeclubs_sheet = bridgeclubs.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var data_bridgeclubs = bridgeclubs_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var numRows = bridgeclubs_sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    var sprshtname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
    for (var i=1; i<=numRows; i++) {
        if (sprshtname == data_bridgeclubs[i][6]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

function one() {
    var C;
    var A = two();
    if (A) {
        C = 35 * A;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would I set `A` and break instead of just returning `A`?

Comment: Thanks a lot torazburo, did not know the meaning of return (I am a just starter and already 67 years old...). Your solution works! Ths again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables.

```
var A;

function two() {
    var bridgeclubs =   SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dfyI1jbz..........TVg4OoixKTz1");
    var bridgeclubs_sheet = bridgeclubs.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var data_bridgeclubs = bridgeclubs_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var numRows = bridgeclubs_sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    var sprshtname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
    for (var i=1; i<=numRows; i++) {
        if (sprshtname == data_bridgeclubs[i][6]) {
           A = i;         
           break;
        }
    }
}

function one() {
     two();
     var C= 35 * A;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is **not** the best approach. That's what function return values are for!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work in a google script environment. It is not possible to declare a value seperate from a function.

Comment: @torazaburo You have right, but it's good to know more solutions instead of only one. Then you can compare them and select the best one.

Comment: The idea of using global variables as a backdoor for what amounts to returning the value of a function is a horrible anti-pattern which should not be give more than the one nanosecond of consideration it takes to reject it.